# "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3" with JSON request

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

Trying to scrape data from a bus transit system. From what I understand this error has something to do with the data returned by the JSON request not being formatted properly. The trouble is, I don't know exactly what the request is returning and I'm totally new to webdev stuff in general.

```
response = requests.get('http://passio3.com/www/mapGetData.php?getBuses=1&deviceId=1683997&wTransloc=1')

print(response)
print(response.json())
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTd03.png)

Comment: "I don't know exactly what the request is returning": so print it out, and then you'll know (`print(response.text)`). You should also check for the response status before attempting to decode the JSON (check `response.status_code`, or call `response.raise_for-Status()`).

Comment: This url is incorrect or you need to put more params to request o change url. I am getting this response: '[{error no systemsAndRoutes}]'

Comment: It will be better if you shared where you captured this API request, as for now this is an invalid API request

Comment: @AlbertoHanna I don't know how to access the API at the moment, but isn't it possible to do it without the API?

Comment: where did you find this url?